# How do I remove a sub class from a nested observable collection in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a nested observable collection for an invoice and I'm currently using the code at the bottom to remove a selected row from the grid control. An example of an invoice would be:

```
  ----------------------------------------------------
  | Item Name | Quantity | Unit Price |  Total Price  |
  ----------------------------------------------------
- |  Coffee   |     1    |    1.00    |     1.00      |
     -------------------------------------------------
    | Item Name | Quantity | Unit Price | Total Price |
     -------------------------------------------------
    |  Creamer  |    1    |    1.00    |     1.00     |  
    |   Sugar   |    1    |    1.00    |     1.00     | 
  ----------------------------------------------------
- |   Bread   |     1    |    1.00    |     1.00      |
     -------------------------------------------------
    | Item Name | Quantity | Unit Price | Total Price |
     -------------------------------------------------
    |   Cheese  |    1     |    1.00    |    1.00     | 
  ----------------------------------------------------
+ |   Water   |     1    |    1.00    |     1.00      | 
  ----------------------------------------------------
```

If I select `Coffee`, `Bread` or `Water`, it successfully removes the item along with its sub items.

But if I select `Creamer`, `Sugar` or `Cheese`, it removes the parent item instead and thereby deleting every sub item it has.

---

*My code is:*

```
int rowUID = Convert.ToInt32(invoiceGC.GetFocusedRowCellValue("InvoiceItemUID"));

for (int i=0; i < Invoice.Count(); i++)
{
    if(Invoice[i].InvoiceItemUID == rowUID)
    {
        Invoice.Remove(Invoice[i]);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        bool subDelete = false;
        for (int j=0; j < Invoice[i].InvoiceItemSub.Count(); j++)
        {
            if (Invoice[i].InvoiceItemSub[j].InvoiceItemUID == rowUID)
            {
                Invoice[i].InvoiceItemSub.Remove(Invoice[i].InvoiceItemSub[j]);
                subDelete = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(subDelete == true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*My class is:*

```
public class InvoiceItemMainClass
{
    private string invoiceItemMainName;
    private decimal invoiceItemMainQuantity;
    private decimal invoiceItemMainUnitPrice;
    private decimal invoiceItemMainTotalPrice;
    private int invoiceItemID;
    private int invoiceItemUID;
    private ObservableCollection<InvoiceItemSubClass> invoiceItemSub;
    public InvoiceItemMainClass(string invoiceItemMainName, decimal invoiceItemMainQuantity, decimal invoiceItemMainUnitPrice, decimal invoiceItemMainTotalPrice, int invoiceItemID, int invoiceItemUID)
    {
        this.invoiceItemMainName = invoiceItemMainName;
        this.invoiceItemMainQuantity = invoiceItemMainQuantity;
        this.invoiceItemMainUnitPrice = invoiceItemMainUnitPrice;
        this.invoiceItemMainTotalPrice = invoiceItemMainTotalPrice;
        this.invoiceItemID = invoiceItemID;
        this.invoiceItemUID = invoiceItemUID;
        this.invoiceItemSub = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceItemSubClass>();
    }
    public string InvoiceItemMainName { get { return invoiceItemMainName; } set { invoiceItemMainName = value; } }
    public decimal InvoiceItemMainQuantity { get { return invoiceItemMainQuantity; } set { invoiceItemMainQuantity = value; } }
    public decimal InvoiceItemMainUnitPrice { get { return invoiceItemMainUnitPrice; } set { invoiceItemMainUnitPrice = value; } }
    public decimal InvoiceItemMainTotalPrice { get { return invoiceItemMainTotalPrice; } set { invoiceItemMainTotalPrice = value; } }
    public int InvoiceItemID { get { return invoiceItemID; } set { invoiceItemID = value; } }
    public int InvoiceItemUID { get { return invoiceItemUID; } set { invoiceItemUID = value; } }
    public ObservableCollection<InvoiceItemSubClass> InvoiceItemSub { get { return invoiceItemSub; } }
}

public class InvoiceItemSubClass
{
    private string invoiceItemSubName;
    private decimal invoiceItemSubQuantity;
    private decimal invoiceItemSubUnitPrice;
    private decimal invoiceItemSubTotalPrice;
    private int invoiceItemID;
    private int invoiceItemUID;
    public InvoiceItemSubClass(string invoiceItemSubName, decimal invoiceItemSubQuantity, decimal invoiceItemSubUnitPrice, decimal invoiceItemSubTotalPrice, int invoiceItemID, int invoiceItemUID)
    {
        this.invoiceItemSubName = invoiceItemSubName;
        this.invoiceItemSubQuantity = invoiceItemSubQuantity;
        this.invoiceItemSubUnitPrice = invoiceItemSubUnitPrice;
        this.invoiceItemSubTotalPrice = invoiceItemSubTotalPrice;
        this.invoiceItemID = invoiceItemID;
        this.invoiceItemUID = invoiceItemUID;
    }
    public string InvoiceItemSubName { get { return invoiceItemSubName; } set { invoiceItemSubName = value; } }
    public decimal InvoiceItemSubQuantity { get { return invoiceItemSubQuantity; } set { invoiceItemSubQuantity = value; } }
    public decimal InvoiceItemSubUnitPrice { get { return invoiceItemSubUnitPrice; } set { invoiceItemSubUnitPrice = value; } }
    public decimal InvoiceItemSubTotalPrice { get { return invoiceItemSubTotalPrice; } set { invoiceItemSubTotalPrice = value; } }
    public int InvoiceItemID { get { return invoiceItemID; } set { invoiceItemID = value; } }
    public int InvoiceItemUID { get { return invoiceItemUID; } set { invoiceItemUID = value; } }
}
```

Comment: I finally got it, turns out the problem was how I was getting the focused row id's value. The GetFocusedRowCellValue doesn't work on detail rows on a GridControl's Master-Detail. I had to use this code instead to get the detail's focused row `int rowUID = Convert.ToInt32(invoiceTable.FocusedView.DataControl.GetCellValue(invoiceTable.FocusedView.FocusedRowHandle, "InvoiceItemSubUID"));`

Answer (score 0):

As Per your logic for removal It will always delete the Parent 
Consider You have Parent Item is "Coffee" with Id =1 and It has SubItem "Sugar" with Id =1 Now When you select "Sugar" ( which is SubItem with the Id =1) and looping through the Items It matches with Parent Item "Coffee"  and remove and your loop breaks.

To achieve Delete of SubItem From your Parent Item you need to supply two arguments/parameters 1) Parent Id and SubItem Id in different method and then you can delete the SubItem from the Parent's SubItem Collection.

Comment: I purposely created UID or Unique ID to address the problem of having duplicate values for conditional uses, they're iterated when adding items to the collection so they never have the same values even if I delete an item, it 's pretty much a sql's Id and only gets truncated if I restart the application. The UID for the following are `Bread = 1`, `Creamer = 2` and so on until `Water = 6`.

Comment: I fixed it, and while your solution didn't help me out exactly, I still want to thank you since you made me double check which row I getting and it turns out the problem was on how I was storing the focused row.

Comment: @KlausBean Glad to know that you found problem and resolved it :)